# How can I get data in relationship database Laravel models with vuejs, axios

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I trying to get data in my table `Personal-Information` witch has foreign key as `user_id`, from table `user` but i cannot get it. Is anyone knows how, Please?

MODELS USER AND PERSONAL RELATIONSHIP

```
class Personal extends Model
 {
 protected $fillable = ['fillable data'];    
 protected $table = 'informations';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTO(User::class);
}
```

}

MY PERSONAL CONTROLLER

```
class PersonalController extends Controller
{

private $personal;

public function __construct(Personal $personal)
{
    $this->personal = $personal;
}

public function index()
{   
    $user = auth()->user();
    if(!$user==null)
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }else
    {
        return view('home' , compact('user'));
    }  
}

public function get()
{
    $user = auth()->user()->personal;
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

MODELS FOR USER RELATIONSHIP

```
public function personal()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Personal::class);

}
```

MY VIEW TEMPLATE

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            form: new Form({
                id: '', 
                name: '', 
                surname: '', 
                identity: '', 
                birthday: '', 
                country: '',
                province: '',  
                county: '', 
                telemovel: '', 
                address: '', 
                facebook: '', 
                tweet:'', 
                linkedin: '',
            }) 
        }
    },
    methods:{    
        loadUsers(){
            axios.get("api/personal").then(({ data }) => (this.form.fill(data)));
        },
        createUser(){
            this.form.post('api/personal')
        },
    },
    created(){
        this.loadUsers();
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be its because you have a syntax error. belongTo is like this in your relationship personal model and also specify foreign key like given below

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id'); }
```

user_id is the foreign key.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but the really thing is that I should install first the a Laravel Passport. After that everything goes well